# Не могу подключиться к веб-интерфейсу PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

После установки PostgreSql , и Pgadmin4 последней версии (7.5)  пытаюсь подключиться через браузер к веб интерфейсу, запускаю PgAdmin , пытаюсь подключиться и бесполезно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом PgAdmin вот такая картина. PostgreSQL 10 доступен, PostgreSQL 15  нет - после ввода пароля происходит бесконечная загрузка, но он не входит туда и пароль не принимается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что журнал логов говорит сразу после попыток таких подключиться.

****2023-08-13 10:04:31,765: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2023-08-13 10:04:31,765: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web****

Установил simple-websocket как он просит, она есть, последняя версия, но бесполезно, ошибка в логах повторяется.

Пытаюсь через PostgreSQL 10 зайти на веб интерфейс но безуспешно, хотя порт 5432 пишу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data файл pg_hba.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data файл postgresql.conf помимо настроек больших по умолчанию имеет вот эту настройку listen_addresses = '*'

Помогите решить проблему эту

Comment: порт веб-сервера не 5432, а 80 и его в строке адреса можно не указывать. На порту 5432 работает сам PG